# Minimum voltage power supply

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have an aircraft instrument panel with a digital multifunction instrument. This instrument has a minimum voltage of 10.5V dc. This is uncommon as most such devices can go down to 9V or lower.

When the aircraft is on final approach or in a sharp descent, when the throttle goes to idle, the overall circuit voltage can temporarily go down to 10V. When it happens the instrument resets. Totals are saved, but current flight is lost as it starts a new one.

I would like to insert on the power supply of this instrument a device that will protect it from low voltage.

Comment: Hello and welcome ... have you considered some kind of battery backup for your panel?

Comment: Electrically, this is very easy to solve, but what are you allowed to change on an (certified) aircraft?

Comment: Yeah, that's an ugly FAA issue. Generally you're not allowed to DIY on airplanes, except in certain countries, certain classes of airplane which have the burden of restrictive rules.  "protect it from low voltage" what do you want it to do, keep working anyway? If you want a UPS that works on 12 volts DC, they make those, they're called a "battery" lol.

Comment: Thank you for all these comments. Let me qualify better   

The aircraft is not certified- it’s an ultralight, otherwise the instrument installation would not be airworthy as is. 

It’s probably very easy but my limited experience doesn’t allow me to spot the sure solution. 

A kind of UPS or low voltage protection should be 1. Lightweight, 2. Waterproof (the aircraft is a seaplane and 3. Withstand 80°C

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boost converter to convert the varying input voltage to a stable (i.e. 12V) output voltage. There are a lot of ready-made modules you can buy.

This of course won't work if the voltage dips all the way down to zero, but if the lowest it'll get is 5V or more (as you mentioned), it's a very simple solution.